# Changing the contents of a pushed notification

Tags: json, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, unusernotificationcenter

I'd like to change the contents of a pushNotification, sent with user, inside of a delegate method for receiving Push Notifications (I am using Firebase FCM)

My plan would be to change the title and body values stored inside of the `userInfo [AnyHashable:Any]` type, and set the userInfo to this modified value.

Per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/1409222-userinfo), it says that userInfo is a get-only property.
Is there any way for me to change the value of userInfo on the client? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change the content of push notifications because the system presents it to the user before informing the application.

If you want to have more control over what your notification should look like, you should use Rich Push Notification (RPN). With RPN, notification presentation is up to you (app side). You can custom text messages, adding images/audios/videos/gifs, and more. But it requires a little extra work.

You may also try to customize the appearance of the notification by using the `Notification Content Extension` but it does not allow you to customize the initial banner (you need to tap the initial banner to see the full notification interface)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/customizing_the_appearance_of_notifications

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about how to change the user info in notification but you can change the push notification contents by creating a NotificationServiceExtension.

Refer this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-image) . This is about send image through firebase notification.
But this will change the contents of the notification.

```
// Modify the notification content here as you wish
self.bestAttemptContent.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ [modified]",
self.bestAttemptContent.title];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have implemented this extension, and would additionally recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MybLsPhz27g&t=308s) to get a grasp of how to implement this, and ensure to use `mutable_contents:1` inside of your notification to a device.